# How can I use interface with generics?

Tags: java, generics, interface

This is my structure.

```
public class FooInfo { ... }

public class FooAInfo extends FooInfo { ... }
public class FooBInfo extends FooInfo { ... }

public interface IFoo<T1 extends FooInfo> {
  void proc(T1 fooInfo);
}

public class FooA implements IFoo<FooAInfo> {
  void proc(FooAInfo fooInfo) { ... }
}
public class FooB implements IFoo<FooBInfo> {
  void proc(FooBInfo fooInfo) { ... }
}
```

And I want to use them like

```
public abstract class FooUser {
  protected IFoo<FooInfo> foo;
}

public class FooAUser extends FooUser {
  public FooAUser() {
    super.foo = new FooA();
  }
}

public class FooBUser extends FooUser {
  public FooBUser() {
    super.foo = new FooB();
  }
}
```

I want to initialize `FooUser`'s `foo` variable in `FooAUser` and `FooBUser` child class.

But It doesn't work because `new FooA()` and `new FooB()` don't have `<FooInfo>`.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make `FooUser` generic:

```
public abstract class FooUser<T extends FooInfo> {
  protected IFoo<T> foo;
}

public class FooAUser extends FooUser<FooAInfo> {
  public FooAUser() {
    super.foo = new FooA();
  }
}

public class FooBUser extends FooUser<FooBInfo> {
  public FooBUser() {
    super.foo = new FooB();
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a generic [wildcard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html) (`?`) on your `foo` parameter:

```
public abstract class FooUser {
  protected IFoo<?> foo;
}

public class FooAUser extends FooUser {
  public FooAUser() {
    super.foo = new FooA();
  }
}

public class FooBUser extends FooUser {
  public FooBUser() {
    super.foo = new FooB();
  }
}
```

---

(Unrelated to the question, but your `proc()` methods in your classes also need to be declared `public`.)

Comment: Every time I add ```FooUser```'s member variable like ```IMember<T1>```, generic types keep increasing. Can I resolve this problem?

Comment: I've tried ```IFoo foo = new FooA();``` and it worked. But it showed me 'Raw use of parameterized class ```IFoo```' warning. I want to reduce generic declarations.